# How to avoid image src string repetition by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

As I have collecting multiple image url by JavaScript from e-book site How to check and avoid repetition of url by JavaScript. By script image URLs loaded as below
var dwnImgpath = imgItem.src();
For loop here;
Output

“images/123.jpg”
“image/234.jpg”
“Image/456.jpg”
“Image/234.jpg”

Comment: Just create a set with those URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a loop over an array containing the sources:

```js
 function start() {
            var src = ["images/123.jpg", "image/234.jpg", "image/345.jpg","image/345.jpg", "Image/456.jpg"];
            src.forEach(function (a, a1) {
                src.forEach(function (b, b1) {
                    if (b == a && a1 != b1) {
                        delete (b)
                    }
                })


            });}
```